# How to put file nameautomatically from text box when save dialog box appear

Tags: vb.net

iam already use this code to save image file
i want when save dialog box appear take the file name from text which inside textbox written by hand or barcode scanner

[image]

```
   Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim data As IDataObject
        Dim bmap As Image

        ' Copy image to clipboard
        SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, 0)

        ' Get image from clipboard and convert it to a bitmap

        data = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
        If data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
            bmap = CType(data.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Image)
            picCapture.Image = bmap
            PictureBox1.Image = picCapture.Image
            If sfdImage.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                sfdImage.FileName = TextBox1.Text
                If InStr(sfdImage.FileName, ".bmp") Then

                    bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

                Else
                    bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting `sfdImage.FileName = TextBox1.Text` before the `If sfdImage.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then` line.  `ShowDialog` is waiting for the user to close the dialog, so your line isn't getting called until after it's no longer visible.

Comment: @omarweeka so you want to close the dialog automatically? So why do show the dialog at all?

Comment: you are right but i need different way to save it automatically by pressing enter key on save button

Comment: If you don't need the end user to enter a file name, you don't need the Save Dialog.  Just use a string variable and supply the full file path and name yourself in your code and use that.

Comment: i dont know the way can you help

Comment: @omarweeka so have a closer look on the line _bmap.Save_.